# viewing java applets without the java process in the background unnecessarily

Tags: google-chrome, java-applet

I'm not keen on installing java.. I don't want an icon in the system tray appearing showing it's some hulk outside the browser that can appear when it wants..I don't want that. 
And I don't want some java.exe process appearing.
I'd like to keep it strictly in the browser, and, I'd like to be able to disable it, and enable it only for some particular site as a one-off.

Comment: ... how do you propose to run Java applets without the jvm ?

Comment: well,  I guess there's no Chrome Addon JVM?   I guess there's no JVM that can just be started and stopped just for a particular site?

Comment: Not that I can recollect.